# CSS float property shows no height?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to CSS, so, this might look silly:

In CSS, i use the property to `float:left` to position a content left to the neighbouring element, now, i have a container for all the elements that have the float property. how do i make the parenting element adjust it's height according to it's content?

the HTML:

```
<div id="page">
<div id="side">
    <p>my sidebar</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>my content</p>
    <p>my content1</p>
    <p>my content2</p>
    <p>my content3</p>
</div>
```

​

the CSS

```
/* the "border:3px solid #000;" are used to make the div border visble*/
#page{
position:relative;
width:400px;
background-color: #F4F0EC;
border:3px solid #000;
}
#side{

border:3px solid #000;
float:left;
}
#content{
float:left;
 border:3px solid #000;
}
```

with the above, the `<div id="page">` look like it has a height of 0px.... how do i make it warp the content ??

since i'm new to CSS, please explain what am i doing wrong, thanks

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/AuSmP/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add `overflow:hidden` for your `div #page` which will allow it to resize to fit its contents.

**[See Working Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/AuSmP/1/)**

**[Learn more about overflow property.](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)**

Alternatively you can also add `<div class="clear"></div>` and then `CSS` `.clear{clear:both;}` to achieve the same.

**[See Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/AuSmP/5/)**

Comment: Dude, I have never been so happy finding out about a new CSS attribute! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Changing Position from relative to absolute can also help you out
Check this [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AuSmP/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you expected? http://jsfiddle.net/AuSmP/4/
just add float:left style to #page will fix the trick, or you could also use clear:both at the bottom